# Error in installation of mit-scheme-9.2

Tags: mit-scheme

I am trying to install mit-scheme-9.2 in linux.
I have successfully downloaded **mit-scheme-9.2-x86-64.tar.gz** from
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/stable.pkg/9.2/mit-scheme-9.2-x86-64.tar.gz

I follow installation instruction properly but i got error in configuration file.I am attaching **error.txt** file that contain a complete configuration process of my system.
Please check error at bottom of file.

**error.txt**

```
Lenovo-G580:~/mit-scheme-9.2/src$ ./configure 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for native-code support... yes, for x86-64
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
etc/create-makefiles.sh mit-scheme-x86-64 x86-64
Makefiles already created.
rm -f machine && ln -s machines/x86-64 machine
rm -f compiler.cbf && ln -s machine/compiler.cbf compiler.cbf
rm -f compiler.pkg && ln -s machine/compiler.pkg compiler.pkg
rm -f compiler.sf && ln -s machine/compiler.sf compiler.sf
rm -f make.com && ln -s machine/make.com make.com
rm -f make.bin && ln -s machine/make.bin make.bin
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile.tools
config.status: creating 6001/Makefile
config.status: creating compiler/Makefile
config.status: creating cref/Makefile
config.status: creating edwin/Makefile
config.status: creating ffi/Makefile
config.status: creating imail/Makefile
config.status: creating runtime/Makefile
config.status: creating sf/Makefile
config.status: creating sos/Makefile
config.status: creating ssp/Makefile
config.status: creating star-parser/Makefile
config.status: creating win32/Makefile
config.status: creating xdoc/Makefile
config.status: creating xml/Makefile
=== configuring in microcode (/home/rishi/mit-scheme-9.2/src/microcode)
configure: running /bin/bash ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking whether backslash-a works in strings... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for working volatile... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for preprocessor stringizing operator... yes
checking for function prototypes... yes
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /bin/grep
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for GCC>=4... yes
checking for native-code support... yes, for x86-64
checking for ELF binaries... yes
checking for exp in -lm... yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking bsdtty.h usability... no
checking bsdtty.h presence... no
checking for bsdtty.h... no
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking fenv.h usability... yes
checking fenv.h presence... yes
checking for fenv.h... yes
checking ieeefp.h usability... no
checking ieeefp.h presence... no
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking sgtty.h usability... yes
checking sgtty.h presence... yes
checking for sgtty.h... yes
checking stropts.h usability... yes
checking stropts.h presence... yes
checking for stropts.h... yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/mount.h usability... yes
checking sys/mount.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/ptyio.h usability... no
checking sys/ptyio.h presence... no
checking for sys/ptyio.h... no
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/timex.h usability... yes
checking sys/timex.h presence... yes
checking for sys/timex.h... yes
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking sys/vfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/vfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/vfs.h... yes
checking termio.h usability... yes
checking termio.h presence... yes
checking for termio.h... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking util.h usability... no
checking util.h presence... no
checking for util.h... no
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking signal.h usability... yes
checking signal.h presence... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking assert.h usability... yes
checking assert.h presence... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for intptr_t... yes
checking for unsigned long long int... yes
checking for long long int... yes
checking for intmax_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for uintptr_t... yes
checking for uintmax_t... yes
checking size of char... 1
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking size of unsigned char... 1
checking size of unsigned short... 2
checking size of unsigned int... 4
checking size of unsigned long... 8
checking size of void *... 8
checking size of intptr_t... 8
checking size of uintptr_t... 8
checking size of intmax_t... 8
checking size of uintmax_t... 8
checking for nlink_t... yes
checking for clock_t... yes
checking for time_t... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for cc_t... yes
checking for speed_t... yes
checking for fenv_t... yes
checking for fexcept_t... yes
checking size of time_t... 8
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for struct tm.tm_gmtoff... yes
checking for struct ltchars... no
checking for struct hostent.h_addr_list... yes
checking for struct sigcontext... yes
checking for struct ntptimeval... yes
checking for struct ntptimeval.tai... yes
checking for struct ntptimeval.time.tv_nsec... no
checking for struct timex... yes
checking for struct timex.tai... yes
checking for struct timex.time.tv_usec... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... (cached) no
checking whether char is unsigned... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... (cached) yes
checking whether getpgrp requires zero arguments... yes
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
checking for utime.h... (cached) yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking whether setpgrp takes no argument... yes
checking whether utime accepts a null argument... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for wait3 that fills in rusage... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for closefrom... no
checking for ctermid... yes
checking for dup2... yes
checking for expm1... yes
checking for fcntl... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for feclearexcept... yes
checking for fedisableexcept... yes
checking for feenableexcept... yes
checking for fegetenv... yes
checking for fegetexcept... yes
checking for fegetexceptflag... yes
checking for fegetround... yes
checking for feholdexcept... yes
checking for feraiseexcept... yes
checking for fesetenv... yes
checking for fesetexceptflag... yes
checking for fesetround... yes
checking for fetestexcept... yes
checking for feupdateenv... yes
checking for floor... yes
checking for fmod... yes
checking for fpathconf... yes
checking for fpgetround... no
checking for fpsetround... no
checking for frexp... yes
checking for fsync... yes
checking for fsync_range... no
checking for ftruncate... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getlogin... yes
checking for getpagesize... (cached) yes
checking for getpgrp... yes
checking for getpt... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for getwd... yes
checking for grantpt... yes
checking for kill... yes
checking for lockf... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking for madvise... yes
checking for memcpy... yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for mktime... yes
checking for modf... yes
checking for nice... yes
checking for ntp_adjtime... yes
checking for ntp_gettime... yes
checking for openpty... no
checking for poll... yes
checking for pollts... no
checking for ppoll... yes
checking for posix_madvise... yes
checking for posix_openpt... yes
checking for prealloc... no
checking for rename... yes
checking for rmdir... yes
checking for pselect... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for setpgrp... yes
checking for setpgrp2... no
checking for shmat... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sighold... yes
checking for sigsuspend... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for statfs... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for sync_file_range... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for times... yes
checking for truncate... yes
checking for uname... yes
checking for utime... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for X... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for long file names... yes
checking ncurses.h usability... no
checking ncurses.h presence... no
checking for ncurses.h... no
checking curses.h usability... no
checking curses.h presence... no
checking for curses.h... no
checking term.h usability... no
checking term.h presence... no
checking for term.h... no
checking termcap.h usability... no
checking termcap.h presence... no
checking for termcap.h... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tparm in -lncurses... no
checking for tparam in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
checking for tparm in -lcurses... no
checking for tparam in -lcurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tparm in -ltermcap... no
checking for tparam in -ltermcap... no
configure: WARNING: No termcap library found; will emulate it
checking openssl/blowfish.h usability... yes
checking openssl/blowfish.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/blowfish.h... yes
checking for BF_set_key in -lcrypto... yes
checking openssl/md5.h usability... yes
checking openssl/md5.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/md5.h... yes
checking for BF_set_key in -lcrypto... (cached) yes
checking mhash.h usability... no
checking mhash.h presence... no
checking for mhash.h... no
checking mcrypt.h usability... no
checking mcrypt.h presence... no
checking for mcrypt.h... no
checking gdbm.h usability... no
checking gdbm.h presence... no
checking for gdbm.h... no
checking db.h usability... no
checking db.h presence... no
checking for db.h... no
checking for pg_config... /usr/bin/pg_config
checking libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for m4... no
configure: error: m4 not found
configure: error: ./configure failed for microcode
```

Did you notice it?
**configure: error: m4 not found**
**configure: error: ./configure failed for microcode**
can someone fix this error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to install `m4` ... BTW, why don't you try installing [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/) ?? Or simply try to find a package providing some Scheme?

Answer (score 0):

To build MIT Scheme on a Debian based system, you first need to install the build dependencies using:

`sudo apt-get install m4 autotools-dev libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev libltdl-dev`

Reference:

> Here's the list of package dependencies that must be installed when building:
>
> m4, autotools-dev, libssl-dev, libncurses5-dev, libx11-dev,
>   libxt-dev, libltdl-dev
>
> And here are some optional packages that are needed for specific
>   purposes like crypto and databases:
>
> libmhash-dev, libmcrypt-dev, libgdbm-dev, libpq-dev, libdb-dev

Source: Chris Hanson on the [mit-scheme-devel mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/mit-scheme-devel/2010-04/msg00013.html).